# Setting up word problem for finding length and width

Tags: polynomials, factoring, rational-functions

Word Problem: The length of a rectangular sign is $3$ feet longer than the width. If the sign has space for $54$ square feet of advertising, find its length and width.

I have not idea where to start. What is the formula to solve this?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts at all on the problem?

Comment: well the problem states that it wants the length and width. so im assuming x + y = 54, x for length and y for the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sides of the rectangle are $x$ (width) and $y$ (length). Now, write down:

1. The equation that tells you that the sign is $3$ feet longer than it is wide.
2. The equation that tells you that the area of the sign is $54$ square feet.

Put these equations either in your question via editing or in the comments under my answer, I will then help you further.

Comment: Equation 1: X = y - 3 Equation 2: X * Y = 54 ?

Comment: Correct. Now, since $x=y-3$, what can you say about the equation $xy=54$? For example, if $x=10$, then $xy=10y$. But you know that $x=y+3$. Can you still substitute the variable?

Comment: would it be Y-3 * Y = 54?

Comment: Writing parentheses corrrectly, $(y-3)y=54$, yes. Now, do you know how to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: so it would become y^2-3y-54=0, once factored it will become (y+6)(y-9). the length would be 9 and the width 6.

Comment: Well done. Wasn't that hard, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Let $w$ be the width of the sign. It is given that the length is $w+3$, and therefore a variable for length is not necessary (though this is essentially just skipping a step of solving the system of equations as given above). Area=width * length, so $54=w(w+3)$. Solving for $w$ is now trivial, you already have a formula for length in terms of $w$.

Answer (score 0):

Sol. 1. Brute force it. Basically, try product of all numbers between 1 and 54. And you will find that the answer is 6 x 9 = 54.

But that trivial so lets see if we can improve.

Sol. 2. Let breath of sign board = x.
This means length of sign board should be = (x+3)

So our solution will be the value of x such that x * (x + 3) = 54
Now either you can solve the quadratic equation x^2 + 3x  =  54.
If you don't know how to solve quadratic equation, that try each value of x till you get x * (x + 3 ) = 54. ( an easier way to brute force :) ). And x = 6 will satisfy the equation.

Hence length =  9 feet and breath  = 6 feet.

Comment: Brute forcing requires another warning. The solutions may not be integers in general.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Don't brute force. Just see if you can guess the values. :)